# Joining multiple tables based on value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP/MYSQL website through which I post two types of content:

1. News Posts (my content)
2. Visitor Submissions (poetry, artwork etc)

Each of these content types has its own individual table, and each has a column that stores the title of the post/submission. There is a third table that I use to store the comments for both the news posts and submissions. I set up the comments table to have a column called **content_category** which would add the value of *"post"* or *"submission"* to track which of the content types it belongs to. There is also another column that stores the primary key/id value of the news post / visitor submission called **content_id**.

The idea is that when pulling the comments from the database, I want to also display the title of the post or the submission. The logic I want to implement is basically this: If the record has a content_category column value of "post", JOIN the POSTS table on post_ID, but IF the content_category column has a value of "submission", JOIN the SUBMISSIONS table on submission_id.

This is my code at the moment but it's not working :(

```
SELECT * FROM comments 
LEFT JOIN posts AS details ON comments.content_id = details.post_id
WHERE comments.content_category = 'post'

UNION

SELECT * FROM comments 
LEFT JOIN submissions AS details ON comments.content_id = details.submission_id
WHERE comments.content_category = 'submission'
```

Your kind help is much appreciated :(

Comment: What do you mean with not working .. you have error .. ?   . or you have worng results?  and in this case show a proper sample of data and expected result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNION needs to have exactly the same number of fields

```
SELECT comments.*, details.some_other_field_from_posts  FROM comments  LEFT JOIN posts AS details ON comments.content_id = details.post_id WHERE comments.content_category
= 'post'

UNION

SELECT comments.*, details.some_other_field_from_submissions FROM comments  LEFT JOIN submissions AS details ON comments.content_id = details.submission_id WHERE comments.content_category = 'submission'
```

Hope it helps